# Conditional loop for category

Tags: categories

I want to show different style for parent and child category how can i do it?
if i browse parent category then show a style and when browse child category then show different style
And how can i show only parent category name and 3 post from this category
like

1.parent category name1

……3post of this category……

2.parent category name 2

……3post of this category……

Answer (score 2):

```
$categories = get_categories( array(
    'parent' => 0,
) );

foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo $category->name;
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'category_name'  => $category->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
    ) );
    foreach ( $posts as $item ) {
        echo get_the_title( $item->ID );
    }
}
```

Something like this print wich you need. But it is very simple example.

Comment: I want for parent category only

Comment: Updated get_categories params. This code will show just parent categories.